# Angular component not updating after Service change until user interaction

Tags: angular

I have a chat service which has a Subject with a boolean type. The service doesn't run this until my auth service runs first as I have AngularFire authState subscribed in my auth service constructor. Once authState changes, it grabs the user uid within the authState and my auth service has a Subject to push the uid to. My chat service subscribes to this uid observable. Once I get a uid, this code runs:

```js
export class ChatService {

    searching: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(
        public adb: AngularFireDatabase,
    ) {

        this.searching.next(false)

        this.userRef = this.adb.database.ref('users').child(uid)

        this.userRef.on('value', snapshot => {

            if (snapshot.child('searching').val()) {
                this.searching.next(true)
                this.connected.next(false)
            }

            if (snapshot.child('connected').val()) {
                this.searching.next(false)
                this.connected.next(true)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

My chat component is subscribed to this in it's constructor with `this.chat.searching.asObservable().subscribe(console.log)`

this logs the changes perfectly fine. Though if I have `{{chat.searching | async}}` in my components HTML anywhere, it wont display the initial `false` value set in the service. It will update when it changes to true (both in the html and console.log), but it wont update the components view when it changes to false until I interact with something in the view despite the console.log in the component still logging false.

**chat.component.html**

```js
<div class="chat">

    uid: {{auth.user.uid}}
    <br>
    searching: {{chat.searching | async}}
</div>
```

**chat.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';
import { NgScrollbar } from 'ngx-scrollbar';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(NgScrollbar) scrollRef: NgScrollbar;
  scrollBar: Subscription

  foobar

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    public chat: ChatService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.chat.searching.asObservable().subscribe(v => {
      this.foobar = v
      console.log(this.foobar)
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: In the example that you provide, you just log the result of the subscription, but are you updating the reference in you component?

Comment: I don't have a reference in my component as I said if I'm doing `{{chat.searching}}` in my html view whereas `chat` in my component is the chat service. Updated answer though as I forgot I'm using `{{chat.searching | async}}` as it's subscription.

Comment: @ErraticFox can you try a `BehaviorSubject` with an initial value?
Like: `new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`

Comment: @GermanBurgardt - I did this about a couple minutes after posting my last comment, still nothing. Again, it'll console.log the updated value, but it doesn't update the view. If I click on a button, it'll update the view with the correct value.

Comment: @GermanBurgardt updated question. BehaviorSubject did make the initial value pop up, it'll also update to true, but updating it to false, it'll stay true until user interaction. I know that if I subscribe to the BehaviorSubject. I think this has something to do with zone not propagating the data properly or something (just a hunch).

Comment: It's pretty weird.
To not waste more time with this, a workaround could be add
`isChatSearching: boolean = false;` in `chat.component.ts` and `this.chat.searching.subscribe(val => this.isChatSearching = val)` in `ngOnInit` of same component. And then `{{ isChatSearching }}` in view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194459/discussion-between-erraticfox-and-german-burgardt). I've already tried that and I've also put a log inside the subscriber to log the variable in the component.ts and it still logs the correct value, but doesn't update the view still.

Comment: @than - added it, the console.log inside the subscriber logs the correct value, but doesn't update the view.